# ASP Excel.Application objExcel.Range("range") freezing

Tags: excel, asp-classic, vbscript

Whenever I use this code,

```
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sPathToTemplate)

oExcel.Range("shipping_name").Value = strShippingName

oWorkbook.Close()
Set oWorkbook = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

The Excel process on the server is freezing, and the cells are never altered. Or at least that's what it seems.

The workbook opens just fine, and if I don't try to change any cell contents, the code completes without error.  But when I add the change back in and refresh the page, the EXCEL.exe process comes up in the task manager, and the script stops responding.  I have to kill the process manually for it to time out.

Anything I can do to get the code working?

Comment: Same thing happens if I use oExcel.Range("shipping_name")

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get a parse error because of the parentheses in your subroutine call `oWorkbook.Close()`

Comment: I think oWorkbook.Close() returns True or something, so that may be why.  I know oExcel.Open(file) returns the workbook, so I wonder what .Close() is returning.  Whatever the case, isn't the parenthesis thing only an issue between Functions and Sub-Routines, and not Methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly due to the fact you are not saving the workbook. On a desktop, this would cause Excel to generate a "Do you want to save the changes?" dialog.

Try adding

```
oWorkbook.saved = true
```

before you close the workbook. This will tell Excel to not be concerned with whether the workbook has changed (but won't save the document). If your asp works, then it's the save dialog that's causing the problem. To actually save the changes, you'll need to call one of the

```
oWorkbook.Save
oWorkbook.SaveAs
```

methods

Comment: My problem is that I planned to use this workbook as a template and save it as a different file, but I haven't gotten to that part.  Would I be able to do a SaveAs with the same result?

Comment: I should think so, as long as your asp has write access to your webserver it should work